# admin_enqueue_scripts not loading any file when not logged in

Tags: wordpress

I'm using `admin_enqueue_scripts` to load my own CSS and JS in the WP-Admin, and I know the JS file is working when logged in, but the CSS file isn't being loaded from what I can see.

I'm checking if logged out, is there any condition that makes this only apply to logged in users? There's nothign to suggest this is the case, and I'm certain my code is right.

Have I missed something here? To me, this should be working, but the style-admin file isn't being loaded on the login page, and there's nothing in the console either.

```
function sg_assets_admin() {

    if(WP_DEBUG === false) {
        wp_enqueue_style('sg-style-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-admin.min.css');
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('sg-style-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-admin.css');
    }

    wp_enqueue_media();

    if(WP_DEBUG === false) {
        wp_enqueue_script('sg-script-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script-admin.min.js');
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script('sg-script-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script-admin.js');
    }

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sg_assets_admin');
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the login page as I am trying to reference doesn't use `admin_enqueue_scripts`, but `login_enqueue_scripts`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_enqueue_scripts/

Answer (score 0):

```
function sg_assets_admin() {

    if(WP_DEBUG === false) {
        wp_enqueue_style('sg-style-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-admin.min.css');
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_style('sg-style-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style-admin.css');
    }

    wp_enqueue_media();

    if(WP_DEBUG === false) {
        wp_enqueue_script('sg-script-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script-admin.min.js',array('jquery'));
    } else {
        wp_enqueue_script('sg-script-admin', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/script-admin.js',array('jquery'));
    }

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'sg_assets_admin');
```

Try above modified code

Comment: pass jQuery in array like array('jquery')

Comment: The CSS isn't loading, not the JS. the JS behaves fine, as explained in my question.